# PUT method request is NULL in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Why the `req` `HttpRequest` object is always `null` when I try to call my function with Postman? I have defined the Body values in Postman settings.

```
[Function("UpdateSettings")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSettings(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = "settings/{id}")]
    HttpRequest req, int id)
{
    // "req" is null here
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

I tried to change the method from `put` to `post` and then the `req` is defined. It's no longer null. But I need to use `put` method here.

The `req` object should not be `null` when I send data to the function.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using _myapp_api.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())
    .ConfigureOpenApi()
    .ConfigureServices((hc, sc) => {
        sc.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(hc.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Base"))
        );
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**myapp-api.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_myapp_api</RootNamespace>
    <DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>/home/site/wwwroot</DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Permissions" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you using a in-process function or isolated?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Isolated.

Comment: I am able to get the [data](https://i.imgur.com/DcxiZj8.png)

Comment: Please share your Program.cs file and .csproj file. Here I am able to get the expected response using in-process function

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Added those files contents to original post.

Comment: There's no EF code in this question. Why is it mentioned at all?

Comment: @Leinonen How are you using `HttpRequest`  and `IActionResult` in isolated function without using `ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication` in your Program.cs file as per the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#aspnet-core-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use ASP .NET core Integration like using `IActionResult`, `HttpRequest` in isolated function, you need to make few modifications as per this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#aspnet-core-integration).

[image]

With the below code, I am able to get fetch the request body using PUT Verb.

**Function Code**-

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp53
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("UpdateSettings")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSettings([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = "settings/{id}")]
        HttpRequest req, int id)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs** -

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**.csproj**-

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Postman**-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The key was to install that missing package and update the existing ones. Now the PUT method works. Strange how the POST worked before.